# React Formik JSON to YAML, then back to JSON on Submit

Tags: reactjs, json, yaml, formik

My goal is to have a JSON object stringified to YAML for a field value then, on form submit, take the YAML and convert it to JSON.

I was able to take the JSON, and use `YAML.stringify(options, null, 2);` to get a YAML value in the field to be edited with [YAML node package](https://eemeli.org/yaml/v1/#yaml).  However, upon submit I'm not exactly sure how to parse the YAML as JSON.

Near the bottom of my component I tried to `push` `JSON.stringify('', null, 0)` to get the value but I keep getting YAML.

How can I get the edited YAML field to parse back to JSON for the data with Formik's `onSubmit`?

Is taking edited YAML and converting it as JSON on submit something that is possible on the frontend or would I have to add backend logic? I found converters but not much in this instance.

My JSON data (focus is on `"options"` key):

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "photo_name": "Testing",
  "options": {
    "test": true,
    "command": [
      "test photo"
    ],
    "max_size": 50,
    "is_prio": false
  },
```

YAML output:

```yaml
test: true
command:
  - test photo
max_size: 50
is_prio: false
```

My React component:

```
import YAML from 'yaml';

const NewPhoto = () => {
  const fetchContext = useContext(FetchContext);
  const [photoList, setphotoList] = useState([]);

  const sleep = (ms) => new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, ms));

  useEffect(() => {
    const getphotoList = async () => {
      try {
        const { data } = await fetchContext.authAxios.get(`/api/photo_data/`);
        setphotoList(data.results);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    };

    getphotoList();
  }, [fetchContext]);

  const initialValues = {
    id: '',
    options: '',
  };

  return (
    <div className="col-xl-12">
      <Formik
        initialValues={initialValues}
        onSubmit={async (values, { resetForm }) => {
          alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
          resetForm();
        }}
        validationSchema={schema}
      >
        {({ isSubmitting, values, setFieldValue, handleChange }) => (
          <Form>
            <FieldArray name="photo">
              {({ insert, remove, push }) => (
                <>
                  {values.photo.length > 0 &&
                    values.photo.map((task, index) => (
                      <div className="row" key={index}>
                        <div className="col-11">
                          <div className="row">
                            <div className="col">
                              <div className="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor={`photo.${index}.step`}>
                                  PHOTO TASK
                                </label>
                                <Field
                                  className="form-control"
                                  as="select"
                                  name={`photo.${index}.id`}
                                  onChange={(event) => {
                                    handleChange(event);
                                    const selectedPhotoTask = photoList.find(
                                      (photoList) =>
                                        photoList.id === event.target.value
                                    );
                                    const selectedOptions = YAML.stringify(
                                      selectedPhotoTask.options,
                                      null,
                                      2
                                    );
                                    setFieldValue(
                                      `photo.${index}.options`,
                                      selectedOptions
                                    );
                                  }}
                                >
                                  <option value="" defaultValue disabled>
                                    ...
                                  </option>
                                  {photoList &&
                                    photoList.map((task) => (
                                      <option key={task.id} value={task.id}>
                                        {task.name}
                                      </option>
                                    ))}
                                </Field>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-12">
                              <div className="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor={`photo.${index}.options`}>
                                  OPTIONS
                                </label>
                                <Field
                                  id="options"
                                  component="textarea"
                                  className="form-control"
                                  name={`photo.${index}.options`}
                                  type="text"
                                  rows="4"
                                  onChange={handleChange}
                                />
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-1">
                          <button
                            type="button"
                            className="btn"
                            onClick={() => remove(index)}
                          >
                            DELETE
                          </button>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    ))}
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    className="btn"
                    onClick={() =>
                      push({
                        id: '',
                        options: '',
                        // options: JSON.stringify('', null, 0),
                      })
                    }
                  >
                    ADD
                  </button>
                </>
              )}
            </FieldArray>
            <button className="btn" type="submit" disabled={isSubmitting}>
              SUBMIT
            </button>
          </Form>
        )}
      </Formik>
    </div>
  );
};

export default NewPhoto;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to save the `values` into their own variable, and then loop through them and apply a `YAML.parse()` for each index.

```
    let submitVals = values;

    for (let index = 0; index < submitVals.photo.length; index++) {
      let optionsText = YAML.parse(submitVals.photo[index].options);
      submitVals.photo[index].options = optionsText;
    }
    console.log(submitVals);
    send(submitVals);
```